# How do I substitute text within an element tag?

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

For

```
checked="checked"

html`${this.checked} < input type=checkbox ${this.checked}>`
```

When I inspect the output in the browser, instead of

> checked < input type=checkbox checked>

I'm getting

> checked `<input type=checkbox <!--{{lit-5238200558676867}}--==$0">`

What am I doing wrong?

NB single quote = back-tick

---

Update

I've worked around it by creating an element, but I'm guessing there is a simpler syntax

```
let cb = document.createElement("input");

cb.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

 if (this.checked) {

   cb.setAttribute('checked', 'true');

 }

 html `${cb}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is that boolean attributes need a `?` prefix. So the correct syntax is:

```
checked: boolean;
html`<input type=checkbox ?checked=${this.checked}>`
```

As an aside, when I initially had 
 `html '<input type=checkbox ?checked=${this.checked}/>'` it threw an error `Boolean attributes can only contain a single expression`. The element needs to not end with `/>` to avoid this.